# How to upload files using PHP - ODBC in Oracle?

Tags: php, oracle, odbc, blob

I've been doing this, I know the connection works, and I'll test it in another project. but now I need to manipulate blob data in oraclo with php using ODBC, but I do not know how to do it.

I'm getting the error from oracle: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00972:
identifier is too long...

> The code: PHP connection odbc with oracle

```
Table in DB
CREATE TABLE ARCHIVOS
(
  ID       NUMBER,
  ARCHIVO  BLOB,
  NOMBRE   VARCHAR2(150 BYTE),
  TIPO     VARCHAR2(150 BYTE)
);
```

> The code: PHP connection odbc with oracle

```
<code>
<?php 
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnGuardar')){
  $id=  filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id');


  $archivo_nombre=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
  $archivo_tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];  
  $archivo_temp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']; 
  $archivo_string=  file_get_contents($archivo_temp);

  $user = "user ";
  $password = "password";
  $driver = "Oracle in OraClient11g_home1";
  $odbc_string = "DSN=INVENTARIOREPORTS;DRIVER= 
  {".$driver."};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=DB;";

  $conn = odbc_connect($odbc_string,$user,$password);

  $sql = " INSERT INTO ARCHIVOS (ID, ARCHIVO, NOMBRE, TIPO) VALUES 
  (".$id.",".$archivo_string.",'".$archivo_nombre."','".$archivo_tipo."') ";

  $res = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

  if ($res) {
    echo 'correcto';
  }else{
    echo 'Error al guardar';
  }

  odbc_close($conn);

  $res = null;
}
?>

<!--FORMULARIO-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title></title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     id <input type="number" name="id" /><br/>
     <input type="file" name="archivo" /><br/><br/>
     <input type="submit" name="btnGuardar" value="Guardar" />
   </form>
 </body>
</html>

</code>
```

I would also like to be able to access these files, can you help me please?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W323U.png)

Comment: Why odbc and not oci* functions?

Comment: It happens that the server is configured for ODBC, I am not allowed to modify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print `$sql` you'll see you have 3 string values but you only quote 2 of them.

The proper way to avoid silly typos like this and SQL injection too is to use prepared statements:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ARCHIVOS (ID, ARCHIVO, NOMBRE, TIPO)
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
$success = odbc_execute($stmt, [$id, $archivo_string, $archivo_nombre, $archivo_tipo]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, apparently I already save the file in the DB.
And in case you need to show the file or download it, do you have any idea how it can be done?

Comment: You retrieve it from DB and echo it?

Comment: You want to use an oracle sequence from PHP, when making an insert.
but it generates this problem.
Use of undefined constant SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA - assumed 'SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA'

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabla (ID_PROBLEMA, HORA_INICIO, PROBLEMA, CAUSA, SOLUCION, HORA_FIN, ID_ASIGNACION) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  $stmt = odbc_prepare($Conex, $sql);

    $success = odbc_execute($stmt, [SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA.nextval,$HORA_INICIO, $PROBLEMA, $CAUSA, $SOLUCION,sysdate, $ID_ASIGNACION] );

Comment: Sorry but comments to answers are not the right place to ask questions. Please use the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.